# Método copiar texto em javascript

Tags: javascript, div

```
<td> 
    <div id="Ei" onclick="getValue()">Click me!</div> 
</td>
<td>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        ShowLMCButton(document.getElementById("Ei"));  
    </script>
</td>
```

Quero fazer com que o usuário copie todo o elemento de uma div, porém está dando o erro: `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`;

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie duas variáveis para guardar o conteúdo:

```
var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv1');
var secondDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv2');
```

Agora só setar o valor na segunda div:

```
 secondDivContent.innerHTML = firstDivContent.innerHTML;
```

Código completo:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyDiv(){
  var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv1');
  var secondDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv2');
  secondDivContent.innerHTML = firstDivContent.innerHTML;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="copyDiv();">
<div id="mydiv1">
  <div id="div1">
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="mydiv2">
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Demonstração http://jsfiddle.net/GCn8j/

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173101/copy-the-content-of-a-div-into-another-div

Comment: Isso ai :D, o que eu queria era esse innerHTML. Muito obg.

Comment: que bom que resolveu :) tem como marcar a resposta como certa? :)